# enbale USB Debugging on damaged screen of mobile

Tags: android

Samsung J3 Pro -Mobile screen is damaged and does not show anything, however its touch is working and I can receive calls etc. 
I have tried `Vysor` and `MyPhoneExplorer` to view the mobile screen on my laptop. but it ask allow `usb debugging`. However my usb-debugging is also enabled.

> **Note:** I have setting saved on one of my machine. I can access and view display on Vysor and change the setting on that PC. when I use another Laptop it ask for
>   allowing prompt option for usb-debugging. How to do on that machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Here]

Touch on **these** parts of the screen to do this.

Comment: It looks fine. But still unable to get the display. in `adb device` it shows unauthorize , does it any thing which matters

Comment: Get the display as in?